# How to open a folder path on windows and linux environment?

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have a functionality in my application where i have to open the location of the certain files when user clicks on a button, For this i am using the following bit of code

```
new ProcessBuilder("explorer.exe",folderPath ).start();
```

This works fine on the Windows platform, but I am not sure whether its going to work on Linux environment or not, unfortunately I don't have Linux environment to test the same, but I came across some post that say it might not work on the Linux.  The other way to do this to use
`Desktop.open`, but post says it also not work on the Linux environment, is there is way to
achieve this on both the platforms?

Comment: *"Desktop.open, but post says it also not work on the Linux environment"*  There are a lot of posts.  What is the URL?

Comment: Are you ignoring my question?

Comment: You should have a Linux environment (e.g. install a dualboot linux&windows on your machine, or at least install Linux in some VM under Windows, or vice versa). Don't pretend developing for Linux without knowing & experimenting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a file, then With java.awt.Desktop you can use something like this:

```
File myfile = new File("/tmp/test.txt");
String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
File dir = new File(path).getParentFile();
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(dir);
}
```

Comment: Thanks TechnoCraft for replying the solution that you have suggested works fine on the windows environment, but my main concern is that whether the same is going to work on linux environment or not..??

Comment: @DurgeshSahu: I am not sure whether the same is going to work on linux environment. But here I found out link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258153/how-to-get-desktop-class-supported-under-linux) for you. Hope it helps you.

Comment: @TechnoCraft it does help, very useful post, thanks. But some how I figured out that the Desktop.getDesktop is depended upon some external libraries (Gnome libraries, that's what the post says) but as i haven't found anything else so i will go with this approach assuming that the client linux machine will have those libraries installed. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
Desktop.getDektop().open(theDirectory);
```

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for more details.