# Typesafe activator - Unable to open web browser

Tags: ip, browser, port

I downloaded "typesafe activator" from play framework. Unfortunately, I have a small problem.
When I run the command "activator-1.0.8/activator ui" I get the following error message:

"Unable to open a web browser!
Please point your browser at:
"localhost"(the editor does not allow me to put down the ip)"

I searched here on the plattform and also googled the problem, but I could not find anything useful.

By the way, I am using linux.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem too. Googling around I found typesafe activator checks if it can open an url in the default browser by invoking the `Desktop.isDesktopSupported()` or the `Desktop.IsSupported(Desktop.Action action)` methods in the java.awt package. These methods require the gnome libraries to work, which might not be installed in your version of Ubuntu.

For me installing the gnome libraries solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome2-0
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11999764/599072

However a quick solution is just to ignore the error message and manually open the browser at the given url (which should be something like 127.0.0.1:8888).