# Desktop.Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path)); giving java.awt.HeadlessException

Tags: java, linux, headless

Hi i have a linux instance and i am using Desktop class.
Code:

```
 String path = request.getParameter("path");
           try {
               Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(path));
               response.getWriter().write("<script>window.close();</script>");

           } catch (IOException ioe) {
                logger.error("doGet method of WordFileOpenerSample threw error:"+ioe.getMessage());
             ioe.printStackTrace();
          }
```

This is working absolutely fine in windows.But gives java.awt.HeadlessException: in linux .  The linux is a headless environment. So, now What are my alternatives or how can i use Desktop class in an headless environment.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? If the Linux is headless, it means it has no GUI environment: no desktop, no windows. So what do you expect this piece of code to be doing?

Comment: I want to open a word file var/www/html/FeedBack/72/MockInterview.docx.The user can edit this file then and there only.Any alternatives or is there anyway i can use this class in a headless environment

Comment: i'm confused, how do you expect the user to edit the file if they are in a headless environment?  like, where is the user editing?  at the command line...?

Comment: Ok.So i got it all wrong.So ,  the user has to download the file and then upload it again to work this in a headless environment?

Comment: I suspect you are confusing your server side with your client side. It probably worked for you on windows because you were running your server on the same machine you are using as desktop. But in general a web server cannot launch applications on the client machine, which is probably what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Ok, So can i work thiso ut by installing gnome libraries.? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8258153/how-to-get-desktop-class-supported-under-linux

Comment: No. Because the web server will not be running on the user's machine. It will be running on a remote machine, and the user is going to communicate with it over HTTP.

Comment: So , the user has to download the file and then upload it again to work this in a headless environment?

Comment: Probably, yes. Even if your server is not headless, that's what the user has to do, or the file will open in the remote machine, not on the user's machine.

Comment: could you explain me the second point:the file will open in the remote machine, not on the user's machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can think on these lines For example :

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(yourURL));
}
else
{
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        if (System.getenv("OS") != null && System.getenv("OS").contains("Windows"))
            runtime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + yourURL);
        else
            runtime.exec("xdg-open " + yourURL);
}
```